# Slow performance in SQL 2014 in SELECT without WHERE clause

Tags: performance, sql-server-2014

We migrated a SQL Server STANDARD 2008 (compatibility level 2005) to a SQL Server DEVELOPER 2014 (compatibility level 2008) and we notice slow performance in the 2014

**SQL SERVER 2014 VERSION**
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3) (KB4022619) - 12.0.6024.0 (X64)
Sep  7 2018 01:37:51
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

**SQL SERVER 2008 VERSION**
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057113) - 10.50.6560.0 (X64)   Dec 28 2017 15:03:48   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

We had been reading a lot of posts about executions plans, indexes and the new SQL 2014 statictis, but in our case a single "SELECT * FROM table" without a WHERE clause, takes the double of time in SQL 2014.

This SQL sentences were run in the SQL Server Management Console

Any clue?

We attach a comparison time table

[image: Comparison chart SQL Server 2008 - SQL Server 2014]

New times using SELECT * into #temp FROM table
[image]

[image]

[image: SQL SERVERS WAIT STATS]

**SQL SERVER 2014 MEMORY USE**
[image]

**SQL SERVER 2008 MEMORY USE**
[image]

**RAM MAP**
[image]

**Memory reported by SQL Console**
[image]

**run spconfigure**
[image]

**Memory script**
[image]

Comment: I think you should add where the console and server are running

Comment: Thanks @malhal. The console runs in the same SQL Server. Both servers has the same configuration, numbers of CPUs and memory. Both are virtual servers

Comment: I updated my answer as it seems we've found the cause of slowness of this pc. The RAM that remains is not sufficient for both the server and console, for server you can fix it by granting SQL Server account lock pages in memory, for client only Win Admin can help you or just run it on another pc

Answer (score 0):

It can be different network configuration or there can be different disks on your servers,
so you should verify how much time your query executes WITHOUT sending result to client.

As the simplest test try to do your select into #tmp table, like this:

```
SELECT * into #t FROM table
```

And compare the execution time on both servers. Here you don't send results to client and exclude network issues.

To compare your servers performance more in depth assuming that the load on these servers is the same please update your questions with the results of this query:
[SQL Server Wait Statistics](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/)

**UPDATE**

From the further investigation we have:

- the client running on this pc is slower than on old server
- the new server constantly reads from disk, `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` is on the
  top of waits statistics and 64% is too high, server needs more RAM

This is because the new server is installed in virtual environment and its RAM is not configured ad dedicated. VM eats it so that server lacks the memory and the client also. The best solution here is to speak to Windows Admin telling him to reconfigure RAM for this server.

In case when Windows Admin doesn't want to reconfigure VM my advise is to run client on other pc so it can have all the memory it needs and  [Enable the Lock Pages in Memory Option (Windows)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows?view=sql-server-ver15)

When SQL Server account has lock pages in memory grant it will take as much memory as it needs (but <= MaxServerMemory configured) without releasing it to VM when VM claims it. This way your server will have 28Gb that was configured to it with 4Gb left to Windows that is perfect.

RAMMAP is a tool that helps you to see the RAM distribution on your server.
I attach my picture where VM was eating RAM from my server so you can see it clearly:

[image: rammap]

Here the server has 64GB of RAM but SQL Server gets only 36Gb even if it needs more, because VM claims it back from server.
Wher SQL Server account has locks pages in memory, it ignores VM claims and only MaxServerMemory configuration limits the RAM it can take.

---

**UPDATE**

Script for RAM distribution

```
DECLARE @OtherClerksTop INT
SET @OtherClerksTop = 5

SET nocount on 
SET TRANSACTIon ISOLATIon LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10000

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @Version VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ServiceName NVARCHAR(100)

SET @Version = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR(100))
SET @ServiceName = CASE WHEN @@SERVICENAME = 'MSSQLSERVER'
                            THEN 'SQLServer:'
                        ELSE 'MSSQL$' + @@SERVICENAME + ':'
                        END

DECLARE @Perf TABLE (object_name nvarchar(20), counter_name nvarchar(128), instance_name nvarchar(128), cntr_value BIGINT, formatted_value NUMERIC(20, 2), shortname NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Perf(object_name, counter_name, instance_name, cntr_value, formatted_value, shortname)
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX ('Memory Manager', object_name)> 0 THEN 'Memory Manager'
    WHEN CHARINDEX ('Buffer Manager', object_name)> 0 THEN 'Buffer Manager'
    WHEN CHARINDEX ('Plan Cache', object_name)> 0 THEN 'Plan Cache'
    WHEN CHARINDEX ('Buffer Node', object_name)> 0 THEN 'Buffer Node' -- 2008
    WHEN CHARINDEX ('Memory Node', object_name)> 0 THEN 'Memory Node' -- 2012
    WHEN CHARINDEX ('Cursor', object_name)> 0 THEN 'Cursor'
    WHEN CHARINDEX ('Databases', object_name) > 0 THEN 'Databases'
    ELSE NULL 
  END AS object_name,
  CAST(RTRIM(counter_name) AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS counter_name, 
  RTRIM(instance_name) AS instance_name, 
  cntr_value,
  CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(20,2)) AS formatted_value,
  SUBSTRING(counter_name,  1, PATINDEX('% %', counter_name)) shortname
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
WHERE (object_name LIKE @ServiceName + 'Buffer Node%'     -- LIKE is faster than =. I have no idea why
    OR object_name LIKE @ServiceName + 'Buffer Manager%' 
    OR object_name LIKE @ServiceName + 'Memory Node%' 
    OR object_name LIKE @ServiceName + 'Plan Cache%')
  AND (counter_name LIKE '%pages %' 
    OR counter_name LIKE '%Node Memory (KB)%'
    OR counter_name = 'Page life expectancy' 
    )
    OR  (object_name = @ServiceName + 'Memory Manager'
        AND counter_name IN ('Granted Workspace Memory (KB)', 'Maximum Workspace Memory (KB)',
                                    'Memory Grants Outstanding',     'Memory Grants Pending',
                                    'Target Server Memory (KB)',     'Total Server Memory (KB)',
                                    'Cnecti Memory (KB)',        'Lock Memory (KB)',
                                    'Optimizer Memory (KB)',         'SQL Cache Memory (KB)',
                                    -- for 2012
                                    'Free Memory (KB)',              'Reserved Server Memory (KB)',
                                    'Database Cache Memory (KB)',    'Stolen Server Memory (KB)',
                                    -- XTP
                                    'Log Pool Memory (KB)')
      )
    OR (object_name LIKE @ServiceName + 'Cursor Manager by Type%'
      AND counter_name = 'Cursor memory usage'
      AND instance_name = '_Total'

      )
-- Add UNIONt to 'Cursor memory usage'
UPDATE @Perf
SET counter_name = counter_name + ' (KB)'
WHERE counter_name = 'Cursor memory usage' 

-- Cvert values from pages and KB to MB and rename counters accordingly
UPDATE @Perf
SET 
  counter_name = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(counter_name, ' pages', ''), ' (KB)', ''), ' (MB)', ''), 
  formatted_value = 
  CASE 
    WHEN counter_name LIKE '%pages' THEN cntr_value/128. 
    WHEN counter_name LIKE '%(KB)' THEN cntr_value/1024. 
    ELSE cntr_value
  END

-- Delete some pre 2012 counters for 2012 in order to remove duplicates
DELETE P2008
FROM @Perf P2008
INNER JOIN @Perf P2012  
   on replace(P2008.object_name, 'Buffer', 'Memory') = P2012.object_name AND P2008.shortname = P2012.shortname
WHERE P2008.object_name IN ('Buffer Manager', 'Buffer Node')

-- Update counter/object names so they look like in 2012
UPDATE PC
SET 
  object_name = REPLACE(object_name, 'Buffer', 'Memory'),
  counter_name = ISNULL(M.NewName, counter_name)  
FROM @Perf PC
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT 'Free' AS OldName, 'Free Memory' AS NewName UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Database', 'Database Cache Memory' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Stolen', 'Stolen Server Memory' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Reserved', 'Reserved Server Memory' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Foreign', 'Foreign Node Memory'
  ) M ON M.OldName = PC.counter_name
  AND NewName NOT IN (SELECT counter_name FROM @Perf WHERE object_name = 'Memory Manager') 
WHERE object_name IN ('Buffer Manager', 'Buffer Node')

-- Add Memory Clerks

-- Add some Memory Clerk descriptis
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mem_clerks_desc') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #mem_clerks_desc
CREATE TABLE #mem_clerks_desc(type varchar(60), descripti varchar(60), is_perf_counter bit)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('CACHESTORE_BROKERTO','Service Broker Transmissi Object Cache', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('CACHESTORE_COLUMNSTOREOBJECTPOOL','Column Store Object Pool', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('CACHESTORE_OBJCP','Object Plans', 1)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('CACHESTORE_PHDR','Bound Trees', 1)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('CACHESTORE_SEHOBTCOLUMNATTRIBUTE','SE Shared Column Metadata Cache', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('CACHESTORE_SQLCP','SQL Plans', 1)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('CACHESTORE_SYSTEMROWSET','System Rowset Store', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('CACHESTORE_TEMPTABLES','Temporary Tables & Table Variables', 1)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('CACHESTORE_XPROC','Extended Stored Procedures', 1)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_QUERYDISKSTORE','Query Store Memory', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_QUERYDISKSTORE_HASHMAP','Query Store Hash table ', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SOSMEMMANAGER','SOS Memory Manager', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE','SOS Node', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SOSOS','SOS Memory Clerk', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL','Database Cache Memory', 1)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR','SQL CLR', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLRASSEMBLY','SQL CLR Assembly', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLCNECTIPOOL','Cnecti Memory', 1)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL','SQL General', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLLOGPOOL','Log Pool Memory', 1)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER','Optimizer Memory', 1)
-- INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLQERESERVATIS','Granted Workspace Memory (Used+Reserved)', 0) -- Exclude completely
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLQUERYEXEC','SQL Query Exec', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLQUERYPLAN','SQL Query Plan', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLSERVICEBROKER','SQL Service Broker', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLSTORENG','SQL Storage Engine', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_SQLTRACE','SQL Trace', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_XE','Extended Events Engine', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_XE_BUFFER','Extended Events Buffer', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('MEMORYCLERK_XTP','In-Memory objects (XTP)', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER','Lock Memory', 1)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('OBJECTSTORE_SERVICE_BROKER','Service Broker (Object Store)', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('OBJECTSTORE_SNI_PACKET','SNI Packet (Object Store)', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('OBJECTSTORE_XACT_CACHE','Transactis Cache (Object Store)', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('USERSTORE_DBMETADATA','Database Metadata (User Store)', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('USERSTORE_OBJPERM','Object Permissis (User Store)', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('USERSTORE_SCHEMAMGR','Schema Manager (User Store)', 0)
INSERT #mem_clerks_desc VALUES('USERSTORE_TOKENPERM','Token Permissis (User Store)', 0)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mem_clerks') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #mem_clerks
CREATE TABLE #mem_clerks(type varchar(60), mem_type varchar(20), pages_mb DECIMAL(20, 2))

IF CAST(SUBSTRING(@VersiON, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @Version, 1)-1) AS INT) >= 11 -- SQL 2012
BEGIN
  SET @sql = '
  SELECT type, mem_type, CAST(SUM(pages_mb)/1024. AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) as pages_mb
  FROM  
  (SELECT type, pages_kb as pages, virtual_memory_committed_kb as virtual, awe_allocated_kb as awe FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks WHERE type <> ''MEMORYCLERK_SQLQERESERVATIONS'') AS t  
  UNPIVOT (pages_mb FOR mem_type IN (pages, virtual, awe)  
  )AS unpvt
  WHERE unpvt.pages_mb > 0
  GROUP BY type, mem_type'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SET @sql = '
  SELECT type, mem_type, CAST(SUM(pages_mb)/1024. AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) as pages_mb
  FROM  
  (SELECT type, single_pages_kb as single_pages, multi_pages_kb as multi_pages, virtual_memory_committed_kb as virtual, awe_allocated_kb as awe FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks WHERE type <> ''MEMORYCLERK_SQLQERESERVATIS'') AS t  
  UNPIVOT (pages_mb FOR mem_type IN (single_pages, multi_pages, virtual, awe)
  )AS unpvt
  WHERE unpvt.pages_mb > 0
  GROUP BY type, mem_type'
END

print @sql 
INSERT #mem_clerks(type, mem_type, pages_mb)
EXEC(@SQL)

-- Build Memory Tree
DECLARE @MemTree TABLE (Id int, ParentId int, counter_name nvarchar(128), formatted_value NUMERIC(20, 2), shortname NVARCHAR(20))

--->>> EXTRA MEMORY (outside of the Buffer Pool) ---  ly for SQL 2008R2 and older
IF CAST(SUBSTRING(@Version, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @Version, 1)-1) AS INT) < 11
BEGIN
  -- Level 1: Total
  INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
  SELECT 
    Id = 2000,
    ParentId = NULL,
    counter_name = 'Extra Server Memory', 
    formatted_value = SUM(pages_mb),
    shortname = 'Extra'
  FROM #mem_clerks mc
  LEFT JOIN #mem_clerks_desc mcd  
  on mcd.type = mc.type
  WHERE mem_type = 'multi_pages'
  -- Level 2: Detailed
  INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
  SELECT TOP (@OtherClerksTop)
    Id = 2100,
    ParentId = 2000,
    counter_name = ISNULL(descripti, mc.type), 
    formatted_value = pages_mb,
    shortname = 'Extra'
  FROM #mem_clerks mc
  LEFT JOIN #mem_clerks_desc mcd  
  on mcd.type = mc.type
  WHERE mem_type = 'multi_pages'
    AND pages_mb > 1.
  ORDER BY pages_mb DESC

  -- Level 2: 'Other Server Memory Extra' = 'Server Memory (Extra)' - SUM(Children of 'Server Memory (Extra)')
  INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
  SELECT
    Id = 2110,
    ParentId = 2000,
    counter_name = '<Other Memory Clerks>', 
    formatted_value = (SELECT SSM.formatted_value FROM @MemTree SSM WHERE Id = 2000) - SUM(formatted_value),
    shortname = 'Other Extra'
  FROM @MemTree 
  WHERE ParentId = 2000
END
---<<< EXTRA MEMORY (outside of the Buffer Pool) ---  ly for SQL 2008R2 and older

------ MAIN
-- Level 1
INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
SELECT 
  Id = 1000,
  ParentId = NULL,
  counter_name, 
  formatted_value,
  shortname
FROM @Perf
WHERE object_name = 'Memory Manager' AND 
  counter_name IN ('Target Server Memory')

-- Level 2
INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
SELECT
  Id = CASE WHEN counter_name = 'Maximum Workspace Memory' THEN 1100 ELSE 1200 END,
  ParentId = 1000,
  counter_name, 
  formatted_value,
  shortname
FROM @Perf
WHERE object_name = 'Memory Manager' AND 
  counter_name IN ('Total Server Memory', 'Maximum Workspace Memory') 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  Id = 1150,
  ParentId = 1000,
  counter_name = 'Foreign Node Memory', 
  formatted_value = SUM(formatted_value),
  shortname = 'Foreign'
FROM @Perf
WHERE object_name = 'Memory Node' AND 
  counter_name IN ('Foreign Node Memory')
HAVING SUM(formatted_value) > 0

-- Level 3
INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
SELECT
  Id = CASE counter_name 
           WHEN 'Granted Workspace Memory' THEN 1110 
           WHEN 'Stolen Server Memory' THEN 1220 
           ELSE 1210
         END,
  ParentId = CASE counter_name 
               WHEN 'Granted Workspace Memory' THEN 1100 
               ELSE 1200 
             END,
  counter_name, 
  formatted_value,
  shortname
FROM @Perf
WHERE object_name = 'Memory Manager' 
  AND counter_name IN ('Stolen Server Memory', 'Database Cache Memory', 'Free Memory', 'Granted Workspace Memory')

-- Level 4
INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
SELECT
  Id = 1225,
  ParentId = 1220,
  counter_name = p.object_name, 
  formatted_value = SUM(formatted_value) - SUM(ISNULL(mc.pages_mb, 0)), -- For SQL 2008 R2 and older subtract multi_pages
  p.shortname
FROM @Perf p
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT descripti as instance_name, pages_mb
  FROM #mem_clerks_desc mcd
      INNER JOIN #mem_clerks mc  
      on mc.type = mcd.type
  WHERE mc.mem_type = 'multi_pages' -- For SQL 2008 R2 and older
    AND ISNULL(mcd.is_perf_counter, 0) = 1
) mc  
on mc.instance_name = p.instance_name 
WHERE p.object_name = 'Plan Cache' 
  AND p.counter_name IN ('Cache')
  AND p.instance_name <> '_Total'
GROUP BY p.object_name, p.shortname

UNION ALL

SELECT
  Id = 1222,
  ParentId = 1220,
  p.counter_name, 
  formatted_value = p.formatted_value - ISNULL(mc.pages_mb, 0), -- For SQL 2008 R2 and older subtract multi_pages
  shortname
FROM @Perf p
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT descripti as counter_name, pages_mb
  FROM #mem_clerks_desc mcd
      INNER JOIN #mem_clerks mc  
      on mc.type = mcd.type
  WHERE mc.mem_type = 'multi_pages' -- For SQL 2008 R2 and older
    AND ISNULL(mcd.is_perf_counter, 0) = 1
) mc  
on mc.counter_name = p.counter_name 
WHERE ((object_name = 'Memory Manager' AND shortname IN ('Cnecti', 'Lock', 'Optimizer', 'Log'))
  )
  AND ISNULL(formatted_value, 0) > 0

UNION ALL

SELECT  -- Memory Clerks (SQL 2008)
    Id = 1222,
    ParentId = 1220,
    T.counter_name,
    T.formatted_value,
    shortname = 'memory clerks'
FROM
(
  SELECT TOP (@OtherClerksTop)
    counter_name = ISNULL(mcd.descripti, mc.type), --  + ' ' + mc.mem_type, 
    formatted_value = mc.pages_mb
  FROM #mem_clerks mc
  LEFT JOIN #mem_clerks_desc mcd  
  on mcd.type = mc.type
  WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(@Version, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @Version, 1)-1) AS INT) < 11 -- SQL 2008 and older
    AND mc.mem_type = 'single_pages'  -- SQL 2008 and older
    AND ISNULL(mcd.is_perf_counter, 0) = 0
  ORDER BY pages_mb DESC
) T

UNION ALL

SELECT   -- Memory Clerks (SQL 2012+)
    Id = 1222,
    ParentId = 1220,
    T.counter_name,
    T.formatted_value,
    shortname = 'memory clerks'
FROM
(
  SELECT TOP (@OtherClerksTop)
    counter_name = ISNULL(mcd.descripti, mc.type) + CASE WHEN mc.mem_type <> 'pages' THEN ' (' + mc.mem_type + ')' ELSE '' END, 
    formatted_value = mc.pages_mb
  FROM #mem_clerks mc
  LEFT JOIN #mem_clerks_desc mcd  
  on mcd.type = mc.type
  WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(@Version, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @Version, 1)-1) AS INT) >= 11 -- SQL 2012 and newer
    AND ((mc.mem_type = 'pages' AND ISNULL(mcd.is_perf_counter, 0) = 0)
      OR mc.mem_type IN ('virtual', 'awe')
    )
  ORDER BY pages_mb DESC
) T

UNION ALL

SELECT
  Id = 1112,
  ParentId = 1110,
  counter_name, 
  formatted_value,
  shortname
FROM @Perf
WHERE object_name = 'Memory Manager' 
  AND shortname IN ('Reserved')
UNION ALL
SELECT
  Id = P.ParentID + 1,
  ParentID = P.ParentID,
  'Used Workspace Memory' AS counter_name,
  SUM(used_memory_kb)/1024. as formatted_value,
  NULL AS shortname
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1220 AS ParentID UNION ALL SELECT 1110) P
GROUP BY P.ParentID

-- Level 4 -- 'Other Stolen Server Memory' = 'Stolen Server Memory' - SUM(Children of 'Stolen Server Memory')
INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
SELECT
  Id = 1222,
  ParentId = 1220,
  counter_name = '<Other Memory Clerks>', 
  formatted_value = (SELECT SSM.formatted_value FROM @MemTree SSM WHERE Id = 1220) - SUM(formatted_value),
  shortname = 'Other Stolen'
FROM @MemTree 
WHERE ParentId = 1220

-- Level 5
INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
SELECT
  Id = CASE WHEN p.instance_name = 'SQL Plans' THEN 1226 ELSE 1230 END,
  ParentId = 1225,
  counter_name = p.instance_name, 
  formatted_value = formatted_value - ISNULL(mc.pages_mb, 0), -- For SQL 2008 R2 and older subtract multi_pages
  p.shortname
FROM @Perf p
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT descripti as instance_name, pages_mb
  FROM #mem_clerks_desc mcd
      INNER JOIN #mem_clerks mc  
      on mc.type = mcd.type 
  WHERE mc.mem_type = 'multi_pages' -- For SQL 2008 R2 and older
    AND ISNULL(mcd.is_perf_counter, 0) = 1
) mc  
on mc.instance_name = p.instance_name 
WHERE p.object_name = 'Plan Cache' 
  AND p.counter_name IN ('Cache')
  AND p.instance_name <> '_Total'

-- Level 6
INSERT @MemTree(Id, ParentId, counter_name, formatted_value, shortname)
SELECT
  Id = 1227,
  ParentId = 1226,
  counter_name,
  formatted_value,
  shortname
FROM @Perf
WHERE (object_name = 'Memory Manager' AND shortname = 'SQL')  -- SQL Cache Memory
    OR object_name = 'Cursor'

-- Results:

-- PLE and Memory Grants
SELECT
    [Counter Name] = P.counter_name + ISNULL(' (Node: ' + NULLIF(P.instance_name, '') + ')', ''), 
    cntr_value as Value,
    RecommendedMinimum = 
        CASE 
            WHEN P.counter_name = 'Page life expectancy' AND R.Value <= 300 -- no less than 300
                THEN 300
            WHEN P.counter_name = 'Page life expectancy' AND R.Value > 300 
                THEN R.Value
            ELSE NULL 
        END
FROM @Perf P
LEFT JOIN -- Recommended PLE calculatis
    (
        SELECT 
            object_name, 
            counter_name, 
            instance_name, 
            CEILING(formatted_value/4096.*5) * 60 AS Value -- 300 per every 4GB of Buffer Pool memory or around 60 secds (1 minute) per every 819MB
        FROM @Perf PD
        WHERE counter_name = 'Database Cache Memory'
    ) R  
    on R.object_name = P.object_name 
       AND R.instance_name = P.instance_name
WHERE 
  (P.object_name = 'Memory Manager' 
  AND P.counter_name IN ('Memory Grants Outstanding', 'Memory Grants Pending', 'Page life expectancy')
  )
    OR -- For NUMA
  (
    P.object_name = 'Memory Node' AND P.counter_name = 'Page life expectancy'
    AND (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT instance_name)
        FROM @Perf 
        WHERE object_name = 'Memory Node'
    ) > 1
  )
ORDER BY P.counter_name DESC, P.instance_name

-- Get physical memory
-- You can also extract this informati from sys.dm_os_sys_info but the column names have changed starting from 2012
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#msver') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #msver
CREATE TABLE #msver(ID int, Name  sysname, Internal_Value int, Value nvarchar(512))
INSERT #msver EXEC master.dbo.xp_msver 'PhysicalMemory'

DECLARE @locked_page_allocations_mb DECIMAL(20, 2)
IF OBJECT_ID('sys.dm_os_process_memory') IS NOT NULL
  SELECT @locked_page_allocations_mb = locked_page_allocations_kb / 1024.FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory

-- Physical memory, cfig parameters and Target memory
SELECT 
  min_server_mb = (SELECT CAST(value_in_use AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'min server memory (MB)'),
  max_server_mb = (SELECT CAST(value_in_use AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'max server memory (MB)'),
  target_mb = (SELECT formatted_value FROM @Perf WHERE object_name = 'Memory Manager' AND counter_name IN ('Target Server Memory')),
  physical_mb = CAST(Internal_Value AS DECIMAL(20, 2)),
  locked_pages_mb = @locked_page_allocations_mb
FROM #msver

-- Memory tree
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 0 as lvl, counter_name, formatted_value, Id, NULL AS ParentId, shortname, formatted_value as TargetServerMemory, CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(20,2)) As Perc, CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(20,2)) As PercOfTarget
  FROM @MemTree
  WHERE ParentId IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CTE.lvl+1,
    CAST(REPLICATE(' ', 6*(CTE.lvl)) + NCHAR(124) + REPLICATE(NCHAR(183), 3) + MT.counter_name AS NVARCHAR(128)), 
    MT.formatted_value, MT.Id, MT.ParentId, MT.shortname, CTE.TargetServerMemory,
    CAST(ISNULL(100.0*MT.formatted_value/NULLIF(CTE.formatted_value, 0),0) AS DECIMAL(20,2)) AS Perc,
    CAST(ISNULL(100.0*MT.formatted_value/NULLIF(CTE.TargetServerMemory, 0),0) AS DECIMAL(20,2)) AS PercOfTarget
  FROM @MemTree MT
  INNER JOIN CTE  
  on MT.ParentId = CTE.Id
)
SELECT 
  counter_name AS [Counter Name], CASE WHEN formatted_value > 0 THEN formatted_value ELSE NULL END AS [Memory MB], Perc AS [% of Parent], CASE WHEN lvl >= 2 THEN PercOfTarget ELSE NULL END AS [% of Target]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ISNULL(Id, 10000), formatted_value DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @sepupic. I updated the SQL Server versions in the problem description. I run the "SELECT INTO temporary table" and is super faster than the "SELECT *" in both servers, but the Management Console is installed in the same server that is SQL Server: Makes sense to you?. In the other hand, the SQL 2014 is faster (double) than SQL 2008 in the "SELECT INTO temporary", but the slowest in the "SELECT *" sentence. I attach the excel comparison file.

Comment: This means that your new server is faster. You only have problems with your client. You did non compare wait statistics (I gave you a link to Randal's query) but Im sure you'll see async_network wait on new server

Comment: I just run the wait statistics. The TOP 3 statistics in the new Server (2014) are:PAGEIOLATCH_SH, CXPACKET and ASYNC_NETWORK_IO
The TOP 3 in the older server (2008, that is faster) are: CXPACKET, ASYNC_NETWORK_IO and PREEMPTIVE_OS_WAITFORSINGLEOBJECT

Comment: It would be better if you wrote % of every wait type. Anyway, if PAGEIOLATCH_SH is the main type of wait on the new server may mean that it has less memory than your old server. Since it's in virtual environment, I doubt you have the same memory on both servers even if you see the same configured value

Comment: You can check your real memory in use by executing this select:  select cast(physical_memory_in_use_kb / 1024. / 1024 as decimal(10,2)) physical_memory_in_use_Gb,
       cast(locked_page_allocations_kb / 1024. / 1024 as decimal(10,2)) locked_page_allocations_Gb,
       cast(virtual_address_space_committed_kb / 1024. / 1024 as decimal(10,2)) virtual_address_space_committed_Gb
from sys.dm_os_process_memory

Comment: Hi @sepupic. Do you recommend to reset wait statistics? I had been running the wait statistics query, and the results change (wait type and wait_s)?

Comment: You should not reset wait statistics, it clearly says that your new server always reads from disk. This can be caused by suboptimal plans but it more probably that the RAM in use is not the same on both servers. Please update your question with the result of the query above showing memory used

Comment: Thanks @sepupic. I just update the memory use information.

Comment: That is what I thought and what waiting stats shows to us. Yor new server has only a half of RAM (6,65Gb vs 13Gb on old server) that's why it constantly reads from disk.

Comment: Yes, that has sense. But for the new server, in the SQL Server Management I saw the memory configuration: Min Memory: 4 GB, Max Memory: 28 GB (the server has 32 GB of memory)

Comment: First of all check SQL Server error log, it writes there how much memory it "see" on this pc, but probably it sees 28Gb. Then run RAMMAP.exe, you can download it from here: https://filehippo.com/download_rammap/ and see how much memory your VM eats (driver locked). When we are sure that there are really 28Gb of RAM but it's eaten by VM I'll tell you how to get your GBs back

Comment: Hi @sepupic. We already run the RAMMAP utility. I updated the question to add the results

Comment: This is very strange, your server needs RAM but doesn't use it, can you please show the result of exec sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)' ?

Comment: Thanks @sepupic. I added the result of exec sp_config to the question.

Comment: Your sp_configure result just confirmed what you said about maxServerMemory, I cannot understand why your server does not use the memory it can get. Can you please show the result of the scipt I pasted in my answer that shows memory distribution on your server

Comment: Thanks @sepupic. This script could be run anytime or is better to run in middle of some intensive data base process?

Comment: You can run it when you want, it's not blocking or resource intensive, it just gets you memory counters

Comment: Thanks @sepupic. I ran the scritp and added the results